# Error reading json file in python Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I have the following json data in a file that I am trying to read in python but I am getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alex C",
        "age": 2,
        "city": "Houston"
    },
    {
        "name": "John G",
        "age": 40,
        "city": "Washington"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bala T",
        "age": 22,
        "city": "Bangalore"
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
JFile = "JData.json"
F = open(JFile, "w")
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen([MyCMD], shell=True, encoding='utf-8', stdout=F)
except Exception as ex:
    print("ERROR: CMD Failed....", ex)
F.close()
try:
    with open(JFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as J:
        JData = json.loads(J.read())
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("invalid json", e)
```

When I try to run this I get this error:

> invalid json Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I got no error. Make sure your file is not empty.

Comment: yup. it's not empty. I double-checked. it is not empty. Thanks for checking

Comment: Apparently `MyCMD` writes invalid JSON to the file.

Comment: I got it. the issue is that it is opening the file before it finishes creating it. that is why it's is giving this error. so by adding proc.wait() resolves the issue

Comment: Also `shell=True` is wrong here. It works on Windows for obscure reasons but you have no reason to need a shell here. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the json file was not yet created when I was trying to read in the code. I had to add proc.wait() to resolve my issue.

```html
JFile = "JData.json"
F = open(JFile, "w")
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen([MyCMD], shell=True, encoding='utf-8', stdout=F)
    proc.wait()
except Exception as ex:
    print("ERROR: CMD Failed....", ex)
F.close()
try:
    with open(JFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as J:
        JData = json.loads(J.read())
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("invalid json", e)
```

Answer (score 1):

That error suggests the interpreter thinks your data is *not* valid JSON, despite the fact that the sample you provided is valid JSON. The code you provided works as intended in my local interpreter (Windows 10, Python 3.9.5, standard `json` library).

I would double check that the `JFile` variable is in fact pointing at the file you think it is and that there is no additional data in the file before your JSON (leading whitespace should be acceptable). If that checks out I would try re-saving your file to ensure it really is `utf-8` encoded or try reading it without explicitly setting `encoding='utf-8'` in your code. I *think* an encoding mismatch would throw a different error but nothing is obviously wrong so it's worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought it was an encoding miss match but I confirmed it is ok. I add code to how I am generating the json file. if I am manually placing the file and removing the code above that is saving the file then it works. I am new to this. maybe it is obvious

Answer (score 0):

what does `JFile` look like? is it a relative path to the file containing your json object?

1. try using the full path (don't forget the file extension).
2. make sure you that the python interpreter has permission to read that file.

Comment: If they didn't have permission to read the file they would get a different exception.

Comment: @mahmoud I confirmed both are ok. I updated the code. please review

Answer (score 0):

The error
`Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
is thrown when `json.load` receives an empty string. Have you double checked if the file you're trying to read contains what you think it does and is in the correct directory? Assuming a file containing a valid JSON, your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I did double-check.